# Calling function with return value in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am new to cakephp. I have a problem with calling the function. here is my issue.

In Contrloller file i get all the values using the following function

```php
public function index() 
{ 
    $conditions = array(
        'order' => array('Histroy.chat_sk DESC')
    );
    $this->set('histroys', $this->Histroy->find('all',$conditions));
}
```

In My model file have the following,

```php
class Histroy extends AppModel 
{
    public $tablePrefix = 'plc_';
    public $useTable    = 'chat_history';
}
```

In my view file i have listed the values using foreach() function and that as follows

```php
foreach ($histroys as $histroy):
    $oper_name = $histroy['Histroy']['operator_fk'];
    $operator_email = $histroy['Histroy']['email'];
endforeach
```

in that opertaor_fk is a field in history table. So i need get the operator name by another table as operators. So i need to call that function in the view.

Ex : In core we can do like as,

```php
$operator_name = operator_name($fetch['operator_id']);
```

Function should be like this:

```php
function operator_name($id)
{
    // Select the value for the matched field in the operator
    return $operator_name;
}
```

In cakephp how can i retrieve the values.

Please help me out to fix this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's really CakePHP 101, I'd suggest that you start by reading the docs: **[Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)**,  **[Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#blog-tutorial) for cake. It'll explain how to create associations and relationships between tables to let you do what is is you want, but in a nutshell, you need to create a relationship between History and Operator models and work from there.

Comment: Thanks i have read the tutorial. now i am using the following association to fetch the value `<?php
class Histroy extends AppModel 
{
       var $name = 'History'; 
   var $belongsTo = 'Operator'; 
}

?>`. and in view file i have `<?php echo $operator['Operator']['username']; ?>`. But i am getting the error `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Histroy.operator_id' in 'on clause'` in my table my field was `operator_fk`. So how can i change this

Comment: i have two model operator and history. i need to fetch the name from operator using `history.operator_fk` field. and history model contains `class Histroy extends AppModel 
{  
   var $name = 'History'; 
   var $belongsTo = 'Operator'; 
 
}` and operator model contains `class Operator extends AppModel 
{ 
   var $name = 'History'; 
   var $hasOne = 'Operator'; }`.

Comment: You've not specified the foreign key in either model.

Comment: With the rest of you're association definitions in the model public $belongsTo = array(
        'Operator' => array(
            'className' => 'Operator',
            'foreignKey' => 'operator_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),);